# Difference between Unit Tests and Functional Tests in User registration module

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd, symfony

I want to write registration module. I assume that I need to create entity model User which will included attributes id, email, password and active.

In this case I should write tests for each get and set method in this class or should I wrote one method setUp which will create new object User and then set parameters?

How I can write tests which check if everything is ok with my user object and another one which check if eg. tests throw exception when email is invalid?

I know how Unit tests works, but I have still problem with decide when tests should be unit and when functional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit test is a code you write for methods in your classes. It allow to test how particular method works in depend on input parameters. I.e. you can test `setEmail($email)` method in your entity, especially if you validate it etc. [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit) is excellent tool to do it. Unit test implies you know everything about the code you're testing.

Functional tests are test you use for product feature testing. I.e. you can test single feature, like user password retrieval or registration. It answers on question `are we building software properly?`. So it's verification of your processes. In compare to unit tests, you actually don't have to know how the methods exactly work. There are a lot tools -- Symfony has [one](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#functional-tests), also [Behat](https://github.com/Behat/Behat) is extremely powerful tool that allow to use natural language (actually Gerkins) to specify tests.

Acceptance tests allow to ensure your product met customer requirements. It answers on the question `did we build the right thing?`. There are a lot of aspects include scalability, security, meeting standards etc. which can be tested in acceptance tests.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explain. One more question: If my User Class has a lot of setters for user object should I write tests for each of them separately and test only eg email or I should create whole test object and then check set email method?

Comment: It's up to you. In my opinion, it will be easier if you have one unit test class per each logic class and keep all the test methods there. Have you taken a look how [tests are written](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Tests/Model/UserTest.php) for existing Symfony projects related user handling?

Comment: Many thanks for link. I didn't check these files. problem solved